# PHP—array_merge_recursive() - no Array for same keys

Tags: php, arrays, merge

```
$php -a
php > $data1 = ['tag' => 'div', 'classes' => [1,2,3]];
php > $data2 = ['tag' => 'section', 'classes' => [2,3,4,5,6]];
php > $result = array_merge_recursive($data1, $data2);
php > print_r($result);
Array
(
    [tag] => Array
        (
            [0] => div
            [1] => section
        )

    [classes] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 2
            [2] => 3
            [3] => 2
            [4] => 3
            [5] => 4
            [6] => 5
            [7] => 6
        )

 )
```

So as describes in the [Docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge-recursive.php):

> If the input arrays have the same string keys, then the values for these keys are merged together into an array[…]

Is there a existing function within PHP that basically does the same, but without merging the same keys into an array, so that the values are overridden and the key kept?

In this case I would like to have that result:

```
Array
(
    [tag] => section

    [classes] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 2
            [2] => 3
            [5] => 4
            [6] => 5
            [7] => 6
        )

 )
```

In regards to the comment of @JustOnUnderMillions:

Yes I wonder, that is not what I would expect of such a function, I would expect a result as I am looking for.

Comment: If the values are overridden then your result will be `$data2`

Comment: as for array within `classes` key:  if *so that the values are overridden and the key kept* then you can't obtain such result `([0] => 1
            [1] => 2
            [2] => 3
            [5] => 4
            [6] => 5
            [7] => 6`), it'll be `(
            [0] => 2
            [1] => 3
            [2] => 4
            [3] => 5
            [4] => 6
        )`

Comment: Do you need the merge to be recursive ?

Comment: yes, this is important here

Comment: Just a note: Does nobody wonder why the function not make an array like `[['tag']=>['div','section'],'classes'=>[[1,2,3],[/*...*/]]]`?? This is typical for php, it merges to vlaues into an array, BUT if you have arrays in the first place, they will be merged toghter?!? Lets say the second one has `'classes'=>'string'` the string will be merge into the given first array. So now thing about more sub arrays (rekursive!!). How does that work..... i dont get it, so i try not to use it.

Comment: I can't get the point of your question ? you need to merge one array from a multidimensional array ?

Comment: I need to merge multiple multidimensional arrays into one, so that the same keys get overridden and merged »subarrays« are unique.

Answer (score 1):

You can deal with this function (recursive and multi-arrays):

```
<?php

$data1 = ['tag' => 'div', 'classes' => [1,2,3], 'foo' => ['bar' => [1,2], 'bar2' => 'foo']];
$data2 = ['tag' => 'section', 'classes' => [2,3,4,5,6], 'foo' => ['bar' => [2,3], 'bar3' => 'foo']];
$data3 = ['tag' => 'section', 'classes' => [7], 'foo' => ['bar' => [5], 'bar3' => 'foo2']];


print_r(custom_array_merge($data1, $data2, $data3));

function custom_array_merge() {
    $arguments = func_get_args();
    $datas = call_user_func_array('array_merge', $arguments);
    foreach($datas as $key => $value) {
        if(is_array($value)) {
            $values = [];
            foreach($arguments as $array) {
                $values[] = isset($array[$key]) ? $array[$key] : [];
            }

            if(array_depth($value) === 1) {
                $datas[$key] = array_unique(call_user_func_array('array_merge', $values));
            }else {
                $datas[$key] = call_user_func_array('custom_array_merge', $values);
            }
        }
    }

    return $datas;
}

function array_depth(array $array) {
    $max_depth = 1;

    foreach ($array as $value) {
        if (is_array($value)) {
            $depth = array_depth($value) + 1;

            if ($depth > $max_depth) {
                $max_depth = $depth;
            }
        }
    }

    return $max_depth;
}
```

Comment: why are you using `call_user_function` instead of a direct function call like: `custom_array_merge(…)`?

Comment: Because you wanted to deal with multiple arrays as input

Comment: Ah, got it… `call_user_func_array`, excuses… like Javascript `Function.prototype.apply()`

Answer (score 0):

To get the result you need use this:

```
function my_array_merge_recursive($array1,$array2){
   foreach($array1 as $key=>&$val){
       if(!isset($array2[$key])){
           contiune;
       }
       if(is_array($val)){
           $val = array_unique(array_merge($val,$array2[$key]));
       } else {
           $val=$array2[$key];
       }
       unset($array2[$key]);
   }
   #if we have entries left in second array
   if(count($array2)){
       return array_merge($array1,$array2);
   }
   return $array1;
}
$data1 = ['tag' => 'div', 'classes' => [1,2,3]];
$data2 = ['tag' => 'section', 'classes' => [2,3,4,5,6]];
$result = my_array_merge_recursive($data1, $data2);
print_r($result);
```

This function is only for this special case.

Comment: that is not recursive and can only handle two arrays as input.

Comment: @philipp Plz read the last line of the answer again, thnx. And if you ask me: _I would like to have that result_ -- You want the arrays be merged in a *very* special way.  There is not function in php that will do that for you. build your own, maybe use this version a starting point.